# Access function from current package when using R CMD check with vignette

Tags: r, sweave

I'm putting together a package; for simplicity with one function and one vignette illustrating its use.

I was able to run `R CMD check packagename` with no difficulties before I tried adding the vignette.
The package has a function`foo.R` in the `R` directory of `packagename` (it makes a plot with base graphics).
The vignette, in the `vignettes` directory, (an `.Rnw` file) calls function `foo` like this:

```
<<fig1, fig=true, echo=true, include=true>>=
df0 <- data.frame(x1=rnorm(10))
foo(df0)
@
```

I'm tying to play 'by the rules' but running `R CMD check packagename` as usual gives:

```
  When sourcing 'foo.R':
  Error: could not find function "foo"
  Execution halted
```

I've tried adding the following to the `.Rnw` file, which didn't help:

```
\begin{document}
\VignetteDepends{packagename}
```

I've also tried this with no success:

```
<<fig1, fig=true, echo=true, include=true>>=
df0 <- data.frame(x1=rnorm(10))
source("foo.R")
foo(df0)
@
```

Note that the `NAMESPACE` file already contains the following:

```
export(foo)
```

Questions:

Do I need to add a specific `source()` command in the `.Rnw` file every time I call a function from the package? If so, how do I specify the path (i.e. where is `R CMD check` starting from when checking the vignette?)

Or should I take the easy way out by adding the following to the `DESCRIPTION` file:

```
BuildVignettes: False
```

(As I'm able to build a `.pdf` from the existing `.Rnw` file).

I'm trying to follow the advice in [**Writing R extensions**](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your vignette needs to have `library("mypkg")` at the top so that your own functions, like `foo`, can be found.  I believe this is because the vignette building runs in a clean environment so it doesn't know about your package or any other for that matter unless you bring it up.

If you have such a line already, put a minimal example of your vignette into your question, and include your `sessionInfo()` as we may need that to figure it out.

Comment: OK, that worked:I'm still getting another error, but it seems to be unrelated.